# ListGrid: Need to show icons in an editable field for a many to one relationship

Tags: smartgwt, smartclient

My problem seems simple. But have not been able to solve till now. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a listgrid showing certain records from a datasource. One of the fields is a many to one. When I try to edit any record, I get a dropdown with all the possible values that the record can have. All fine thus far. The issue is that all the dropdown values are displayed as simple text. I wish them to be displayed as shown [in this link](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#styled_combobox_category).

The requirement is to have "A SelectItem with icons" on the listgrid.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use ListGridField.setEditorType() to customize the editor shown for a field.  This API takes a FormItem, so pass a SelectItem configured similarly to the sample you linked to.